# Laravel log, how to retrieve the level?

Tags: laravel, logging, monolog, laravel-4.2

How can I retrieve the log level in Laravel?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
if ( Log::isInfo() ) {
   ...
}
```

for instance, in log4java, you have the methods isDebug, isInfo, etc.

In the example, the idea is that **isInfo** tests if a message in **Info** level would be logged, so, if the log level is debug or info, it returns true.

The idea is to bypass some piece of code that I only execute to log some detail.

(i'm still using Laravel 4.2)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Could you explain with a use case what you want to do?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I edited the question to clarify it a little.

Comment: I assume your passing some sort of log level? How is this being passed by any chance? By a .env file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, surfing the API documentation in Laravel and Monolog, I arrived at this solution:

```
if ( Log::getMonolog()->isHandling( Log::getMonolog()->toMonologLevel("INFO") ) ) {
   ....
}
```

I'd prefer something prettier, but it works...